# Joomla 3 versioning approval

Tags: joomla-3.x, versions, super-user

I was wondering if anyone knew of any kind of extension which will allow a manager to edit / update the content (articles) in the backend - but only a Super User can approve the changes prior to it going live?

I'm thinking it would work somehow with version control, but I'm not entirely sure. I've done some searching but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at ‘My Content and Workflow’? It does take over com_content completely and can be difficult to configure but it may suit.

Comment: I had a look and there was a lot of bad reviews about it, saying that it doesn't work, and breaks the standard article manager.

Comment: It replaces the article manager and is incompatible with other plugins that work with the standard article manager.

Comment: FLEXIcontent - offers versioning and workflow:
https://flexicontent.org/documentation/faq/81-acl/272-about-workflow-item-state-and-document-versioning-and-notification-system.html